# dns configuration for openfire xmpp server

Tags: xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I want to use XMPP server in my app to handle messages but I'm having issues configuring my server. When I login to my Openfire admin panel I get a warning telling me that my DNS configuration appears to be missing or incorrect. My question now is, how can I create DNS SRV records for my host? I have searched all over the net for a solution but none helped me.

[My openfire admin page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvGmv.png)

Answer (score 0):

the value for the xmpp.fqdn property should be the full network name of the server that is running Openfire, the name that clients would use to connect to Openfire.Maybe your current value is incorrect and you have to edit it.

you can edit fqdn under system properties

Comment: you mean i should make it same with my computer name?

Comment: @Eric not your computer name.when you are installing Openfire there is a field called XMPP DomainName that you have to fill.that's your xmpp server name

Comment: the value in my XMPP DomainName does it have to be my computer name?

Comment: @Eric no it can be anything you like

Comment: then how do i get rid of that warning beside my host name asking me to create dns configuration? could that be the reason my app is unable to connect to xmpp server?

Comment: @Eric yes that's the reason.just uninstall Openfire and reinstall it.this time just put normal name in xmpp domain name

Answer (score 0):

That error in Admin Console means that DNS managing records for dialup.org domain doesn't have a SRV record pointing to XMPP service. It seems that you have installed Openfire on a regular desktop and expect it to work on the Internet. For this you have to have some internet domain and have proper DNS records on that domain.